# putting information nt working

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a "racing" website where I am recording racers results, but I am trying to enter their results in all at once. shown below is the code

Comment: Can you show the error?
And you forgot } at the end of the for loop.

Comment: Can you show me the error too?

Comment: No error comes up....when I have results to enter for two racerIDs, i'll enter both but only one stores

Comment: I don't think `$rank`, `$timetaken`, `$reID` are arrays

Comment: @Arian so how could I solve that?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_GET` data **never** goes directly in a query.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you believe when you have multiple `<input name="" />` you think that creates a array `$_POST[]`, that is not true...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $reID = $row['reID'];
    $racerID = $row['racerID'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$reID<input type='hidden' name='reID' value='$reID'>"; 
    echo "<td>$racerID<input type='hidden' name='racerID' value='$racerID'>"; 

    echo"<td><input type='text' name='rank'>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='timetaken'>";   

}
```

you are over writing the reID, racerID, rank, and time taken every time it is printed out... by default it takes the last one.

what you could do to solve this is:

```
$count = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $count++;

    $reID = $row['reID'];
    $racerID = $row['racerID'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$reID<input type='hidden' name='reID$count' value='$reID'>"; 
    echo "<td>$racerID<input type='hidden' name='racerID$count' value='$racerID'>"; 

    echo"<td><input type='text' name='rank$count'>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='timetaken$count'>";   

}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='count' value='$count' />";
```

That way each value is unique...

Then instead of this:

```
$rank=$_POST['rank'];
$timetaken=$_POST['timetaken'];
$reID=$_POST['reID'];
$racerID=$_POST['racerID'];
$count_racerID= count($_POST['racerID']);
```

do this

```
$count = $_POST['count'];
for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
    $rank[] = $_POST['rank'.$i];
    $timetaken[] = $_POST['timetaken'.$i];
    $reID[] = $_POST['reID'.$i];
    $racerID[] = $_POST['racerID'.$i];
}
$count_racerID = $count;
```

now you have arrays!

For your SQL statement...

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO RaceResults (rank, timetaken, reID, racerID) VALUES ('$rank', '$timetaken', '$reID', '$racerID')");
```

should be

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO RaceResults (rank, timetaken, reID, racerID) VALUES ('$_rank', '$_timetaken', '$_reID', '$_racerID')");
```

---

The final product should be something like this:

The input form:

```
$reID = $_GET['reID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM RaceEventRacer WHERE reID = $reID");

$count = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $count++;

    $reID = $row['reID'];
    $racerID = $row['racerID'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$reID<input type='hidden' name='reID$count' value='$reID'>"; 
    echo "<td>$racerID<input type='hidden' name='racerID$count' value='$racerID'>"; 

    echo"<td><input type='text' name='rank$count'>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='timetaken$count'>";   

}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='count' value='$count' />";
```

and the SQL should be:

```
$count = $_POST['count'];
for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
    $rank[] = $_POST['rank'.$i];
    $timetaken[] = $_POST['timetaken'.$i];
    $reID[] = $_POST['reID'.$i];
    $racerID[] = $_POST['racerID'.$i];
}
$count_racerID = $count;

for($i=0;$i<$count_racerID;$i++){
    $_rank= mysql_escape_string($rank[$i]);
    $_timetaken= mysql_escape_string($timetaken[$i]);
    $_reID= mysql_escape_string($reID[$i]);
    $_racerID= mysql_escape_string($racerID[$i]);

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO RaceResults (rank, timetaken, reID, racerID) VALUES ('$_rank', '$_timetaken', '$_reID', '$_racerID')");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: @user3455546 I edit a part, you must have not put in... make sure you have `echo "<input type='hidden' name='count' value='$count' />";` in your code

Comment: @user3455546 yes, I added the updated sql statement to my answer

Comment: @user3455546 also you need to keep the for loop that I didn't touch there... don't remove that... `for($i=0;$i<$count_racerID;$i++){
        $_rank= mysql_escape_string($rank[$i]);
        $_timetaken= mysql_escape_string($timetaken[$i]);
        $_reID= mysql_escape_string($reID[$i]);
        $_racerID= mysql_escape_string($racerID[$i]);`

Comment: @user3455546 I figured out what the problem was... I updated the first for loop... copy that into the code.

Comment: This part:`for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
    $rank[] = $_POST['rank'.$i];
    $timetaken[] = $_POST['timetaken'.$i];
    $reID[] = $_POST['reID'.$i];
    $racerID[] = $_POST['racerID'.$i];
}`

Comment: @user3455546 I updated it to show correctly, what is wrong with it

Comment: It is my browser issue I think, could you edit it to show the sql statement only